# How to list only the file names in HDFS

Tags: shell, hadoop

I would like to know is there any command/expression to get only the file name in hadoop. I need to fetch only the name of file, when I do `hadoop fs -ls`  it prints the whole path.

I tried below but just wondering if some better way to do it.

```
hadoop fs -ls <HDFS_DIR>|cut -d ' ' -f17
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It seems [hadoop ls does not support any options to output just the filenames](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html#ls), or even just the last column.

If you want get the last column reliably, you should first convert the whitespace to a single space, so that you can then address the last column:

```
hadoop fs -ls | sed '1d;s/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f8
```

This will get you just the last column  but files with the whole path. If you want just filenames, you can use basename as @rojomoke suggests:

```
hadoop fs -ls | sed '1d;s/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f8 | xargs -n 1 basename
```

I also filtered out the first line that says `Found ?x items`

**Note**: beware that, as @felix-frank notes in the comments, that the above command will not correctly preserve file names with multiple consecutive spaces. Hence a more correct solution proposed by Felix:

`hadoop fs -ls /tmp | sed 1d | perl -wlne'print +(split " ",$_,8)[7]'`

Comment: Thanks a ton !! It worked !! My need was the full path so.. Thanks @rojomoke also for answering

Comment: please use this hdfs dfs -ls /data/*.txt* | rev | cut -d\  -f1 | rev, above code doesn't support all the file names ....

Comment: Also note that, The first line `Found ?X items` is not shown when listing file with glob pattern e.g. `/path/to/*.log` . A better, more precised way of replacing: `hdfs dfs -ls /path/*.log | sed 's/  */ /g;/Found [0-9]* items/d' | cut -d\  -f8`

Answer (score 48):

The following command will return filenames only:

```
hdfs dfs -stat "%n" my/path/*
```

:added at Feb 04 '21

Actually last few years I use

`hdfs dfs -ls -d my/path/* | awk '{print $8}'`

and

`hdfs dfs -ls my/path | grep -e "^-" | awk '{print $8}'`

Comment: `hadoop fs` is deprecated, use `hdfs dfs` instead

Comment: Only returns the filename (and * doesn't work it seem to work).

Comment: great answer, I am not sure why awk and sed trickery would be needed with this being available.

Comment: it is working only as if I am running a single command. if I am running it in for loop it is not giving the expected result. it is separating file name on basis of spaces.

Comment: @jirislav `hadoop dfs` is deprecated, not the `fs` one. The latter is perfectly fine. As to the answer, be cautious as it returns **basenames**, not the full filenames

Comment: Any reason why we need the quotes round the %n? This seems to work just fine: `hdfs dfs -stat %n my/path/*`

Comment: Actually last few years I use `hdfs dfs -ls -d my/path/* | awk '{print $8}'` or `hdfs dfs -ls my/path | grep -e "^-" | awk '{print $8}'`

Answer (score 29):

I hope this helps someone - with version 2.8.x+ (available in 3 as well) -

```
hadoop fs -ls  -C  /paths/
```

Comment: Perfetto, exactly what I needed, Thanks  !

Comment: but if the directory is having multiple files then this command is giving all the file path as a single string. please suggest how to get in new line all the file path

Answer (score 2):

One more solution I use often. There are few related things:

- list files and dirs only without `Found x items` with

`hdfs dfs -ls -d mypath/*`

- keep full path only with

`hdfs dfs -ls -d mypath/* | awk '{print $8}'`

- only file names

`hdfs dfs -ls -d mypath/* | awk '{print $8}'| while read fn; do basename $fn; done`

- and in additional use path templates if necessary:

`hdfs dfs -ls -d {my,his}path/*.{txt,doc}`

Answer (score 1):

```
 hadoop fs -ls  -C  /path/* | xargs -n 1 basename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the basename command, which strips any prefix ending in '/' from the string.

```
basename $(hadoop fs -ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Below Command return only the File names in the Directory.
Awk Splits the list by '/' and prints last field which would be the File name.

`hdfs dfs -ls /<folder> | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'`