# hadoop fs -ls storing only the paths to a file

Tags: python, bash, hadoop

I am looking through a Hadoop file system. With the command

`hadoop fs -ls /path/to/dir1*`

I will look through every directory that starts with `dir1` and return their files

The output will be something like

```
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r-- 3 sys_blah_blah  moredate /path/to/dir10/file1.py
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r-- 3 sys_blah_blah  moredate /path/to/dir10/file2.py
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r-- 3 sys_blah_blah  moredate /path/to/dir10/file3.py
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r-- 3 sys_blah_blah  moredate /path/to/dir11/file1.py
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r-- 3 sys_blah_blah  moredate /path/to/dir11/file2.py
...
```

The only piece of information I am interested in is the path to file portion. How can I store only the paths into another file? Ideally, I would like an output of a file with only the paths within that file.

Initially, I thought about running the command and storing it's output into a file and then parse the new file and grab the paths with regex and placing them into a new file but that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `grep` here since `hadoop fs -ls` hardly provides any useful options.

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/to/dir1* | grep -oE "/(.*/)?" > outFile.dat
```

If only one entry for each path is needed, just pass it to `uniq`. eg :

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/to/dir1* | grep -oE "/(.*/)?" | uniq > outFile.dat
```

Looks pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

I do not quite understand your question, but something like should should get you started

```
while read prot digit user group fn; do
   echo $(dirname "$fn")
done < <(hadoop fs -ls /path/to/dir1*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop file-system API (org.apache.hadoop.fs) can be used to retrieve HDFS data from Java (any other compatible language) and subsequent operations (regex) can be done.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569172/how-to-list-only-the-file-names-in-hdfs) by [anirudh.vyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1525079/anirudh-vyas), `-C` option will also output paths only:

```
hadoop fs -ls -C /path/
```