# Get the two first files from HDFS

Tags: bash, hadoop, command-line, hdfs

Is there a way to get the two first files from HDFS using command line?. My hadoop version is 2.7.3

I have a folder in HDFS with multiple files, that another application is puting the there:
      /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile1.json
      /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile2.json
      /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile3.json
      /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile4.json

I need to work just with the first two files based on time, so if list the content using:

```
 $ hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/Lab01/input

-rw-------   3 huser dev       668 2019-02-13 11:34 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile1.json
-rw-------   3 huser dev        668 2019-02-13 11:36 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile2.json
-rw-------   3 huser dev        668 2019-02-13 11:38 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile3.json
-rw-------   3 huser dev        668 2019-02-13 11:41 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile4.json
```

In order to get the two first files from the directory I simple pip the command using head -2 to get:

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/Lab01/input | head -2

-rw-------   3 huser dev       668 2019-02-13 11:34 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile1.json
-rw-------   3 huser dev        668 2019-02-13 11:36 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile2.json
```

The normal command to get files from hdfs is using -get:

```
  hdfs dfs -get /user/Lab01/input/fileName
```

So thats why right now I'm trying to merge this two commands:

```
$ hdfs dfs -get /user/Lab01/input | hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/Lab01/input | head -2
```

But I don't get the desire result, I just get a message giving me the output from the last command (hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/Lab01/input | head -2) :

```
-rw-------   3 huser dev       668 2019-02-13 11:34 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile1.json
-rw-------   3 huser dev        668 2019-02-13 11:36 /user/Lab01/inpu/ingestionFile2.json
```

Comment: Got it, I'm editing the question

Answer (score 2):

You can't pipe a `-get` to an `-ls`

You need to **first** `-ls | head -2`, then `awk` and cut out the filenames you are listed in, and then individually `-get` those two.

Something like this should get the names only

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/Lab01/input | head -2 | awk '{print $8}'
```

Also - [How to list only the file names in HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569172/how-to-list-only-the-file-names-in-hdfs)

Then add just "`| xargs hdfs dfs -get`" to download the files